# Генерация srс в javascript

Tags: javascript, веб-программирование

Имеется клиентское приложение, которое подгружает с удаленного сервера javascript следующим образом:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://192.168.0.1/ind.php"></script>
```

Как сделать так, чтобы src каждый раз генерировалось случайным? А именно `src="http://192.168.0.1/ind?=rand.php`

?=rand - вот эта часть.

Comment: document.getElementById('`ваш_скрипт`').src = `"http://192.168.0.1/" + "случайное_число" + ".php"` , а `случайное_число` зависит от ваших критериев и задаётся через Math.random

Comment: @lexxl
К сожалению в клиенте нельзя использовать getElementById. Пишет getElementById is not a function.